# Is it possible to move where the arrow is with FPPopover?

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, uipopovercontroller, fppopover

I know it's possible with FPPopover to move it to the top, bottom, left or right, and if you assign it to a view, it will point to that view, but what if you're assigning the FPPopover to a CGPoint, like I am in the image below?

[image]

Here, I don't want it over the ôO• (it's a bunny, leave me alone), I want it over the Aa, but I don't know how to move the arrow.

And before anyone suggests to just assign it to that buttons view, that places it too high up, I want it closer to the actual icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible with the `presentPopoverFromPoint:` method in FPPopover, just adjust the x point when you make the CGPoint and it will be further over.